# Emailing Director of Big 4?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, recruitment, hiring-process, applications

So, I attended a career fair where I got the opportunity to speak with the Director of Operations of a Big4 company. We had a very fruitful conversation about the company and his management style.  He seemed very impressed with my credentials and invited me to attend the first round interview with the managers.

The following day, he  emailed me stating that

> It was a pleasure to meet you and our HR team will be in touch to arrange the Round 1 interview with our Managers.Have a great week ahead!

That was 3 weeks ago. I have not heard from the company since then. I'm thinking of emailing him, but I have no idea what to say. 
Any Suggestions please?

Comment: This reads more like a show off than an actual question. What is the problem? Why don't you just write: "I didn't hear back from you."?

Comment: What is Big4? Would "big company" be enough to describe your question?

Comment: Just email him, already (but don't mention your chronic indecisiveness at the interview)

Answer (score 3):

If he told you he would arrange a first interview with HR for two weeks ago, it is legitimate to reply asking if he has done it or not. Just try to not make a big deal out of it. Since you already have his email contact, you can just write a line asking if he got the time to look into it or not, then thank him nicely for taking the time.

Though it is not unlikely that he forgot, I wouldn't keep my hopes too high after three weeks. But maybe he did indeed forget about it.